# Extract specific fields from a column in PostGreSQL 11.0

Tags: regex, postgresql, case

I have following column in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
col1                        start     end 
Q13563:p.I853A              853       853
P12004:p.[R5A;K110A]        5         5 
P12004:p.[R5A;K110A]        110       110 
P13569:p.N1303K             1303      1303 
P14770:p.S142_W143delinsGS  142       143
```

I would like to apply a regex to extract the following fields in below order.

```
col1                        start     end      col2
Q13563:p.I853A              853       853      p.I853A
P12004:p.[R5A;K110A]        5         5        p.R5A
P12004:p.[R5A;K110A]        110       110      p.K110A
P13569:p.N1303K             1303      1303     p.N1303K
P14770:p.S142_W143delinsGS  142       143      p.S142_W143delinsGS
```

I am using following regex to extract the desired information.

```
CASE 
     WHEN start = "end" AND col1 LIKE '.*:p.[A-Z\d+]+' 
     THEN 'p.'||(regexp_match(col1, '([A-Z]'||start||'[A-Z])'))[1] 
     ELSE col1
END AS col2,
```

The above regex also matched the alphabets before ':p'. How can I achieve the desired output.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that, in order to user regex in a 'likeish' fashion, you need to use `~`, not `LIKE`.

Then, in your `~` statement, you need to search for the range of digits `0-9`, `\d+` is not going to cut it inside those square brackets.  Furthermore, you should be matching for the square bracket characters (hence `\[\]`).

Finally, in the `else` portion, you should also be searching with a pattern, not just returning the whole column.  Or else you'll get the stuff before 'p.'.

```
case 
    when start = "end" and col1 ~ '.*:p.[\[\]A-Z0-9]+' 
    then 'p.'||(regexp_match(col1, '([A-Z]'||start||'[A-Z])'))[1]
    else (regexp_match(col1, 'p\..*'))[1]
    end as col2
```